# url rewright - how pick a word from a url and process

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I want to re wright like below mentioned

From : www.example.com/products/abc12345-aaa-bbb-ccc.html
To :   www.example.com/products.php?id=abc12345

As you can c the "from" address is requesting from user 
and "to" address is actual link
how can i pick the first word "abc12345" from first link and apply to second link
My website is php based and mysql
any help will be appreciated

Comment: From : www.example.com/products/abc12345-aaa-bbb-ccc.html 

 To : www.example.com/products.php?id=abc12345

Comment: Please include your code.  Explain which parts work and which don't. We can help with errors, but not with code writing.

Comment: sorry here is my code ==  RewriteRule    ^products/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$    products.php?id=$1    [NC,L]  ==      but its not working

Comment: the user will c  ==  www.example.com/products/abc12345-aaa-bbb-ccc.html

       and  .htaccess  need to convert to  ==  www.example.com/products.php?id=abc12345

Comment: Added a Rewrite rule with a similar regex for htaccess (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- The relevant part of the "from" URL always ends with "/products/".
- The product id is a string of non-special characters, digits, and underlines.

### Code

PHP script:

```
<?php
    $fromurl = '     http://www.example.com/products/abc12345-aaa-bbb-ccc.html';
    $tourl = preg_replace('%([^\s]*?/products)/([A-Za-z0-9]*?)([^A-Za-z0-9])%i', "\r\n\$1.php?id=\$2", $fromurl);
    if (preg_match('%([^\s]*?/products)/([A-Za-z0-9]*?)([^A-Za-z0-9])%i', $fromurl, $regs)) {
        $tourl = $regs[1] . '.php?id=' . $regs[2];
    } else {
        $tourl = "";
    }
    echo $tourl . '<br />';
?>
```

.htaccess file (→ not tested)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)products/([A-Za-z0-9]+)(.*) $1/products.php?id=$2  [NC,L]
```

### Result

> http://www.example.com/products.php?id=abc12345

Comment: thanks for your reply , but i am trying to do with .htaccess on server - really sorry.. i dint mentioned that..

Comment: my present code == RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ products.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: Added a Rewrite rule with a similar regex for htaccess (not tested).

Comment: Where? In a .htaccess file - really?

Comment: i removed "$1/" now its working fine butt its note loading the css and images

Comment: The reason for that could be that the css and image paths are relative paths in the generated HTML code. And since the root path has changed, these files are expected to be stored in the new root path. And, yes, you are absolutely right with removing the $1 variable - sorry!

Comment: Have a look at the _base_ html tag (<base href="http://www.example.com/" />). It could be helpful, but also could create new problems.